# Ternary operator on style with React Js Es 6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to add the following ternary operator to show my button if I am logged in and If I am not to hide it. The following below keeps throwing me an error.

```
<img src={this.state.photo} alt="" style="{isLoggedIn ? 'display:' : 'display:none'}"  />
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it: style={ isLoggedIn ? { display:'block'} : {display : 'none'} }

Comment: I have already added the same answer buddy

Comment: Doh, yeah just wrote out it in here, disregard quotes. Long day...

Answer (score 98, accepted):

What you provide to style attribute should be an object. Since we write js code in jsx between curly braces, you ll insert an object there.

Remember, you need to camelCase all css props. ( font-size ==> fontSize )

```
<img 
  src={this.state.photo} 
  alt="" 
  style={ isLoggedIn ? { display:'block'} : {display : 'none'} }  
/>
```

or

```
<img
  src={this.state.photo} 
  alt=""
  style={ { display: isLoggedIn ? 'block' : 'none' } }  
/>
```

Answer (score 12):

The ternary should be like below:

```
style={isLoggedIn ? { display:'block' } : { display:'none' }}
```

Remove quotemarks - it should work then (assuming `isLoggedIn` is a boolean-ish).

Comment: isLoggedIn can also be: 
1) A list which is evaluated as false if it's empty. 
2) An empty string which is evaluated as false if its null/ undefined.
3) A number which is evaluated as false if it is 0.

Answer (score 3):

In case instead of inlining the style one may want to use the value that is under the styles const, that's a way to do this:

```
function nameFunction(props) {
    return (
        <Button style={props.isSelected ? styles.Active : styles.Inactive }>{props.title}</Button>
    );
}

const styles = {
    Active: {
        backgroundColor: 'orange'
    },
    Inactive: {
        backgroundColor: 'grey'
    },
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do something like this:

```
const styles = {
    display: isLoggedIn ? 'block' : 'none'
}
```

The other answers seem fine as well, just a cosmetic change...